# How do I find the center of the set of matrices $A$

Tags: group-theory

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 
 a & b\\
 0 & 1\\
 \end{bmatrix}$ where $a \ne 0$

I think this is essentially the subset of all invertble matrices and the center of $GL_n(\mathbb{R}) = kI_2$

So $k.I_2 \subset Z(A)$

However I think using computation the center of $A$ is only the identity matrix. Where am i making a mistake?

Comment: $A$ is a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb R)$ but its centre may not be related to the centre of $GL_2(\mathbb R)$ for two reasons: (a) If a matrix belongs to the centre of $GL_2(\mathbb R)$ it may not belong to $A$, let alone to the  centre of $A$, which is what you see here, and (b) If a matrix belongs to the centre of $A$, it commutes to all matrices in $A$ but it may not commute with all matrices in $GL_2(\mathbb R)$. Thus better not rely on the centre of $GL_2(\mathbb R)$ and go back to the definition of centre.

Comment: Generally, if $G\le H$ are two groups, you can say $Z(G)\le Z(H)\cap G$ but not much more.

Comment: Sets don't have centers. Groups have centers.

Comment: Note that $kI_2\not\in A$ for $k\neq 1$.

Comment: The group you mean is the [affine group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group) ${\rm Aff}(\Bbb R)$. It is well known what its center is.